# RadioGroup taking up too much space in vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have an activity with a vertical linear layout. The top **half** of the screen should be a Plain TextView while the bottom **half** should be a RadioGroup that has four Radio Buttons in it.

I set the TextView and the RadioGroup to both have `android:layout_weight="1"`

Before I put buttons into the RadioGroup, the layout was fine because the RadioGroup and the TextView both took up half the screen. But after dragging in the radio buttons and setting them all to `android:layout_weight="1"`, the RadioGroup with the four buttons in it now takes up more than half of the screen.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample Question Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Choice #1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Choice #2"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Choice #3"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:checked="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Choice #4"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:checked="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

This problem also occurs if I only place 2 or 3 buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your TextView and RadioGroup to `android:layout_height="0dp"`
When you use weight, you are giving an instruction to calculate the heights or widths(depending on if it's a vertical or horizontal layout) based on the weights you supply. In this case you are also giving the instruction to calculate the height based on 'wrap_content', these conflicting instructions are causing a problem.

The same goes for your RadioButtons. Whenever you use layout_weight, your height or width should be 0dp.